# developing cross platform games for android and iPhone?

Tags: android, iphone

I know this question has been asked before but I really couldn't find anything that would suit my needs..So I want develop a 2d game that is something like Draw Something. the game is not really heavy on graphics or anything like that so what is the best Development enviroment for my game 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game Development with Cocos2D. Read From Here....

[Game Tutorial1](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/)

[Game Tutoria 2](http://dev.lethain.com/notes-on-cocos2d-iphone-development/)

[Game Tutorial 3](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2009/01/xcode-template-for-cocos2d.html)

Comment: As @Nammari provided link is useful for u.

Answer (score 1):

you should start with [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki) this will help you to write cross platform 2-D games for android and iOS